# Need help displaying the value of a range slider

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am trying to display the output of a slider through JS. Upon running I am met with an error. 'Cannot read property of null'.

HTML code:

```
<div class = 'sliderContainer'>
    <h1> Select Password Length</h1>
    <input type = 'range' min='8' max='16' value='10' id='myRange' class='slider'>
    <p>Password Length: <span id='length'></span></p>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
var output = document.getElementById('length');
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML=this.value;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not getting any error as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document probably hadn't loaded the input before  you tried selecting it. Add an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
  var output = document.getElementById('length');
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
})
```

```html
<div class='sliderContainer'>
  <h1> Select Password Length</h1>
  <input type='range' min='8' max='16' value='10' id='myRange' class='slider'>
  <p>Password Length: <span id='length'></span></p>
</div>
```